# Swift - Performing background task

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I'm trying to run this code in the background when a notification is received:

```
window?.rootViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("ResetStatusBar", object: nil)
```

So I've placed this code in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` like so:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print("Remote notification received in didReceiveRemoteNotification with fetchCompletionHandler")

    // just pop to rootViewController
    window?.rootViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("ResetStatusBar", object: nil)
}
```

This code executes when a notification is received when the app is active, or if the user clicks on the notification that is received, however, if I receive a notification, ignore it, and then open the app (that I did not kill, just pressed the home button on), the changes have not taken effect in the application.

Here are somethings I'm currently doing:

- Sending `'content-available': 1` in the push notification payload
- Have `remote notifications` checked under capabilities for background modes

This is also how I'm registering for push notifications in my AppDelegate file:

```
let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert,.Badge,.Sound], categories: nil)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Any ideas why my code isn't executing? Is it because it's a UI change?

P.S. here's what my push notification payload looks like:

```
let payload = {
  default: notificationDisplayText,
  APNS: {
    aps: {
      alert: notificationDisplayText,
      sound: 'default',
      badge: 1,
      'content-available' : 1
    },
    notificationId: notificationId
  }
}
```

Am I correct in putting the `content-available` key inside the `aps` object, or should I be nesting it directly inside the `APNS`object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to process an unhandled notification when the app starts up, you do that in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, using  `.remoteNotification` key in Swift 3 (`UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey` in Swift 2.3) in the `launchOptions` dictionary.

As [the documentation for `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623117-application) says:

> If the app is not running when a remote notification arrives, the method launches the app and provides the appropriate information in the launch options dictionary. The app does not call this method to handle that remote notification. Instead, your implementation of the [`application(_:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623032-application) or [`application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application) method needs to get the remote notification payload data and respond appropriately.

---

Unrelated, remember that in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` you must call `completionHandler` when you're done processing the notification.

As [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application) says (and the emphasis was in the original):

> As soon as you finish processing the notification, you *must* call the block in the handler parameter or your app will be terminated. Your app has up to 30 seconds of wall-clock time to process the notification and call the specified completion handler block. In practice, you should call the handler block as soon as you are done processing the notification. The system tracks the elapsed time, power usage, and data costs for your app’s background downloads. Apps that use significant amounts of power when processing remote notifications may not always be woken up early to process future notifications.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. So just to summarize, didReceiveRemoteNotification will be called if the app is in the background, correct? And if the app is not running, meaning not even suspended, the notification will be added into the launchOptions dictionary? And lastly, do I just call the completion handler in didReceiveRemoteNotification like this: completionHandler()? Or am I supposed to pass data in?

Comment: Ah I see, I pass in .NewData or .NoData

Answer (score 1):

There are two areas in the app delegate:

If you want something to continue running the background after the user presses the home button...
`func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) { ...}`

If you want something to happen if the user goes back into the application...
`func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) { ...}`

so if you want something to happen in the background..such as send or receive notifications, you'll want to use appDidEnterBackground...

Comment: What would I put in appDidEnterBackground? I thought didReceiveRemoteNotification would be called automatically when a notification is received in the background.. Is that not the case?